# Certification test error on supported API test

Tags: c#, .net, api, windows-phone-8.1, app-certification-kit

I have an error from the **certification** test and I can't seem to resolve it. Errors found are:

> • This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=System.Security.Cryptography.Aes. Module=MSCORLIB.
>   File=System.Core.dll.
>
> • This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform. Module=MSCORLIB.
>   File=System.Core.dll.
>
> • This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.#ctor. Module=MSCORLIB.
>   File=System.Core.dll.
>
> • This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=System.SystemException. Module=MSCORLIB. File=System.dll.
>
> • This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=System.SystemException.#ctor. Module=MSCORLIB. File=System.dll.
>
> • This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=System.SystemException. Module=MSCORLIB. File=System.Xml.dll.
>
> • This API is not supported for this application type -
>   Api=System.SystemException.#ctor. Module=MSCORLIB.
>   File=System.Xml.dll.

The `mscorlib module` is part of the `Windows Phone 8.1 framework`. The project is for `Windows Phone 8.1 RT`, a universal app.

What I have tried to resolve the issue is starting a new project to refresh the references, but it didn't do anything. I've tried adding and removing libraries, but it didn't do anything. I've tried removing the assembly, but I can't seem to.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows/Windows Phone RT project only support a subset of .net APIs. You can get a full support list from [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232(v=vs.140).aspx).

The assembly is needed, don't try to move it. But for Windows/Windows Phone RT project, System.Security.Cryptography.Aes is not supported for this projct type.

I guess you may try to migrate from a silverlight app to Runtime app. Because the System.Security.Cryptography.Aes is supported in Silverlight app. [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207211(v=vs.105).aspx) is for avaliable .net APIs for Windows Phone silverlight app.

So please find out where you used it and remove it. Then try to implement the functions using the class [CryptographicEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx) in namespace [Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.cryptographicengine.aspx) in the [Windows API subset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've made a new project, introduced the packages and assemblies needed one by one and found the faulty one. It was an assembly no longer used that came with a previous port from Silverlight to Runtime. WACK doesn't give me any problems now.